# How can I reference a Master view in a different project in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC solution, and inside I had 2 MVC Website projects.

I'm interested in creating a 3rd project called "Shared", where I can reference the shared views/content between the two sites so I have only one place to edit them.

- WebUI.Site1 (ASP.NET MVC Site)
- WebUI.Site2 (ASP.NET MVC Site)
- WebUI.Shared (Newly created ASP.NET MVC Site)

How can I reference a Masterview's location if it is in a different project?

So, normally at the top of a view I would reference a Masterview like so:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Tabbed.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<WebUI.ViewModels.Admin.EditProfileViewModel>" %>
```

However,

Now, that "Tabbed.Master" isn't in the local project, it is in a difference project in the solution.  I've created a reference to the project but I don't know how to reference Tabbed.Master from WebUI.Site1 to WebUI.Shared?

Something like:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="WebUI.Shared.Views.Tabbed.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<WebUI.ViewModels.Admin.EditProfileViewModel>" %>
```

Doesn't work.

How can I reference the location of things like masterviews, css files, images across projects like that?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of MasterViews, you need to find a filebased solution. The virtual path is one way to do it, but I think you will get in trouble at some point: How do you handle the file references when you use the internal Visual Studio web server?

And think of the pain you suffer when this virtual path is missing in IIS.

Visual Studio let you link to files from other projects. Those files will be copied over at compile time:

> Right-click in Solution Explorer -> Add existing item... -> select files -> Add As Link

Personally, I don't care for this feature. But it seems to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the masterpage lives at `WebUI.Shared Root/Views/SharedPage.Master`

Try creating a virtual directory under both `WebUI.Site1` and `WebUI.Site2` pointing to `WebUI.Shared`:

```
WebUI.Site1/Shared => WebUI.Shared Root
WebUI.Site2/Shared => WebUI.Shared Root
```

From within `WebUI.Site1` and `WebUI.Site2` use the following path to access the masterpage: `~/Shared/Views/SharedPage.Master`

I don't think the IDE will be able to keep track of the reference, but it should work on the server.

**EDIT:** WebUI.Site1 and WebUI.Site2 may need a reference on WebUI.Shared.

Comment: This will not work.  You cannot simply point to an aspx/ascx or SiteMaster in another Virtual Path and have it become part of your code base.

Comment: @Nissan Fan - Yes, you can. I just set up a test project to verify my assertion. IIS doesn't care if a given masterpage is in the same web project as the web root. As long as the references and paths are findable from the website root, IIS is happy. This assumes you are using IIS to set up the sites - this technique won't play nice with Visual Studio's built in ASP.NET Development Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom `ViewEngine` if you want to use a different place than the project's View folder to store your views.

Take a look at this [prototype](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/22/scripted-db-views.aspx) by [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/). It's about storing the views in the database, but it should give you an idea regarding where to start.